# How to write type signature for Data.Vector

Tags: haskell, types

The following code compiles on GHC-7.8.3, but I can't figure out how to write a explicit type signature for `f`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable
import Data.Vector.Generic (freeze, thaw, Mutable, Vector)
import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimState, PrimMonad)
import Control.Monad.ST (runST, ST)

f v = Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.read v 0 >>= 
      Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.write v 0 >> 
      return v

g :: Vector v a => v a -> v a
g v = runST $ (thaw v) >>= f >>= freeze

main = return ()
```

`f` here is just a function that does some work on a mutable vector and returns a mutable vector. I've done a dummy `read` and `write` just to force the type to be a vector.

So how can I write a type signature for `f`?

**Note:** I've significantly edited and the question to clarify and simplify it.

Comment: Why not `f :: Monad m => a -> m a`?

Comment: use the `:t` command in ghci, and you'll get what @András suggested. Note that the monomorphism restriction is by default turned off in ghci 7.8.3 but (IIRC) not in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

That type for `f` doesn't really make sense, precisely because type families are non injective (which is exactly what it tells you). You are saying `f` takes a `Mutable v (PrimState m) a`, but that cannot determine what `v` actually is - this is the meaning of non-injective. Then, the output must *depend on `v`*. But again you don't know what `v` is.

In this case the solution is obvious: give `f` the type `Monad m => a -> m a`. But in general, you have to pass the type `v` to the function somehow. Typically you would write

```
f :: (PrimMonad m, Vector v a) 
  => proxy v -> Mutable v (PrimState m) a -> m (Mutable v (PrimState m) a)
f _ =  return
```

---

The inferred type of

```
f v = read v 0 >>= 
      write v 0 >> 
      return v
```

is

```
(MVector v a, PrimMonad m) => v (PrimState m) a -> m (v (PrimState m) a)
```

The argument to the function isn't a type family application. This is precisely the explicit type you should give it. The type `v` is known. If you were to try to give it the type

```
(PrimMonad m, Vector v a) => Mutable v (PrimState m) a -> m (Mutable v (PrimState m) a)
```

like before, you get the exact same error.

Comment: I don't understand why without a signature I need to pass a proxy but with one I do. Could you look at the updated question above?